# Xamarin.Forms HttpClient send get request using a simple fourSquare API-KEY

Tags: xamarin.forms, authorization, httpclient, foursquare, api-key

I am trying to get a connection to the Places AIP of foursquare. (https://developer.foursquare.com/reference/place-search)
This needs me the send the following authorization header:

{ "Authorization" : "<API_KEY>"} and not { "Authorization" : "<SOME_SCHEMA> <API_KEY>"}
SOME_SCHEMA being "Basic", "Key" or any other type.
--header 'Authorization: API_KEY'

I tried to set is like so
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new

`AuthenticationHeaderValue(Constants.API_KEY);`

According to MSDN documentation this should work. but all I get is an exception saying that the header type is invalid..

Spend the day trying to found a way. but nothing I tried so far works.

I did text over curl and my api-key is good and so is the request. I really just need to get the HttpClient to accept not having a schema/type for Authorization.

Comment: have you tried using `Headers` property on the `HttpRequest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.
it will allow to have a authorization header that does not contain an auth type.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

                request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", Constants.API_KEY);
```

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. Could you please mark it as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems？  Thanks in advance. :)